# How to optimize an arbitrage portfolio when taking into account different speeds of mean reversion?

Tags: arbitrage, portfolio-optimization, mean-reversion

In portfolio optimization, it is insufficient to just note the size of price deviation - that only tells the amount of profit if held to maturity. One also needs to take into account reversion speed - faster reversion means more profits per unit of time.

How is this implemented in practice?